# How to show/print angular reactive form data on screen and after that in jQuery table

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am able to get and print data from template driven form in Angular but unable to done with reactive form and then I have to show it on jquery table.

Comment: Read this: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

All reactive form classes provide a `value` property you can access in the component or bind to templating.

If you're accessing a FormControl, the value will be for the specific control.

A FormGroup will provide an object representing all of its controls.

A FormArray will provide an array of either FormControl or FormGroup values.

More on reactive forms: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms